# iOS video Orientation

Tags: ios, video, orientation, landscape, portrait

iOS6 iPhone project orientation is forced to portrait mode only. I now added a video which plays as it should in portrait mode only. How do I change the orientation of only the video to landscape? Thanks.

Comment: Can you publish the code you are using? The problem may be in your UI? Have you checked all the UI elements and rotation specs?

Comment: In the project summary I have set to use portrait mode only, so no code to force the orientation. I used the default code to play the movie with default settings: _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
    [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];